# Python to C# Zlib decompression conversion

Tags: c#, python

It tooks me hours trying to figure out how to mimic the exact decompression in this project: https://github.com/crimsoncantab/aok-hotkeys/blob/master/modules/hkizip.py but to no avail.

If you go to this website: http://aokhotkeys.appspot.com/ you can click any preset and download it to see for yourself.

The decompression is supposed to output a .hki file to text file

This is my attempt, which may not be as accurate as in the python project linked above:

```
private string ZlibCodecDecompress(byte[] compressed)
{
    int outputSize = 2048;
    byte[] output = new Byte[outputSize];

    // If you have a ZLIB stream, set this to true.  If you have
    // a bare DEFLATE stream, set this to false.
    bool expectRfc1950Header = false;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ZlibCodec compressor = new ZlibCodec();
        compressor.InitializeInflate(expectRfc1950Header);

        compressor.InputBuffer = compressed;
        compressor.AvailableBytesIn = compressed.Length;
        compressor.NextIn = 0;
        compressor.CompressLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.Level8;

        compressor.OutputBuffer = output;




        foreach (var f in new FlushType[] { FlushType.None, FlushType.Finish })
        {
            int bytesToWrite = 0;
            do
            {
                compressor.AvailableBytesOut = outputSize;
                compressor.NextOut = 0;
                compressor.Inflate(f);

                bytesToWrite = outputSize - compressor.AvailableBytesOut;
                if (bytesToWrite > 0)
                    ms.Write(output, 0, bytesToWrite);
            }
            while ((f == FlushType.None && (compressor.AvailableBytesIn != 0 || compressor.AvailableBytesOut == 0)) ||
                   (f == FlushType.Finish && bytesToWrite != 0));
        }

        compressor.EndInflate();

        return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

This method returns: "Ionic.Zlib.ZlibException: Bad state"

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: returns, or throws an exception? in case of exception, on which line (include full call stack if possible).

Comment: Here http://prntscr.com/jrzo3b

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder Providing screenshots for critical parts of your question is bad practice. Provide the required info ***as text*** in the body of your answer please.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using `ZlibCodec` and not `ZlibStream`?

Comment: @spender sorry about that, I wouldn't mind to use other libs

Comment: No, I'm talking about  `Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream` in the same library.

Comment: I found the code like that, and it seems like it's required

Comment: I think the best clue is the detail message "invalid stored block lengths". [start here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10587090/1132334), maybe your input is garbage?

Comment: @dlatikay hahah probably... could you suggest something better? ..God knows for how i have been trying